# Nuxt 2.13 full static AWS S3 issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nuxt.js

Nuxt 2.13 now gives you the option of turning your `universal` application into a [full static site](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static/).

I upgraded nuxt to `2.13.3`, set the target: `static` in the `nuxt.config.js` and then I run `nuxt build && nuxt export`

Now I have static file's in the /dist folder. When I use `MAMP` to view the /dist folder everything works fine, I can navigate to subpages and refresh the page.

**The problem is when I upload to S3 + Cloudfront**

The S3 bucket is set to static web hosting. The `Index document` and `Error document` are set to `index.html` - When I navigate to to to the bucket content I am able to load the page and navigate to subpages. However when I refresh a subpage then the user is shown the `index` page.

On the s3 bucket I have tried enabling all public access - this did not work.

Here is my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cdn-frontend/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

On `cloudfront` the `Default Root Object` is set to `index.html`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

what is the file name for your fallback or error page ? In nuxt config, you can give below option to generate a file with different name than index.html,

```
  generate: {

    fallback: '404.html',
}
```

This during the generate operation will create a 404.html file and you can use the same in your static website hosting as an error page.